# Tight Binding Hamiltonian for graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, graphene, tight-binding

The TB Hamiltonian for the tetragonal lattice is 
$ \hat H_0 = -J\sum_{m,n} (\hat a_{m+1,n}^\dagger \hat a_{m,n}+\hat a_{m,n}^\dagger \hat a_{m,n+1}+h.c.) $

How can this be derived for the hexagonal lattice?

Comment: Your title talks about a tight-binding Hamiltonian but the body of your question talks about a Hubbard Hamiltonian, which has an extra on site term which does not appear in Hamiltonian you have written down. What are you actually after?

Comment: TB Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

Graphene has two atoms per unit cell belonging to sublattices A and B. Nearest neighbor hopping takes place only between atoms of different sublattices:

$$
\hat{H} = -t \sum_j a^\dagger\left(\mathbf{r}_j\right) b\left(\mathbf{r}_j\right) 
+ a^\dagger\left(\mathbf{r}_j\right) b\left(\mathbf{r}_j + \mathbf{d}_1\right)
+ a^\dagger\left(\mathbf{r}_j\right) b\left(\mathbf{r}_j + \mathbf{d}_2\right) + \mathrm{h.c.}\,.
$$

The Hamiltonian tells you that for an A-sublattice atom inside the unit cell at $\mathbf{r}_j$, there are three nearest neighbors: one in the same unit cell and two more in the unit cells shifted by the lattice vectors $\mathbf{d}_1$ and $\mathbf{d}_2$. Write the Hamiltonian in the momentum space:

$$
\hat{H} = -t \sum_j \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_\mathbf{q} a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}e^{-i\mathbf{r}_j \cdot\mathbf{q}}\right] \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{q}'} b_{\mathbf{q}'}e^{i\mathbf{r}_j \cdot\mathbf{q}'}\right] 
\\
 -t \sum_j \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_\mathbf{q} a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}e^{-i\mathbf{r}_j \cdot\mathbf{q}}\right] \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{q}'} b_{\mathbf{q}'}e^{i\left(\mathbf{r}_j+\mathbf{d}_1\right) \cdot\mathbf{q}'}\right]
\\
 -t \sum_j \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_\mathbf{q} a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}e^{-i\mathbf{r}_j \cdot\mathbf{q}}\right] \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{q}'} b_{\mathbf{q}'}e^{i\left(\mathbf{r}_j+\mathbf{d}_2\right) \cdot\mathbf{q}'}\right]
 + \mathrm{h.c.}\,.
$$

Here, $N$ is the number of unit cells in the system. Performing the summation over $j$ gives $N\delta_{\mathbf{qq}'}$ so that

$$
\hat{H} = -t \sum_\mathbf{q} a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}  b_\mathbf{q} 
-t \sum_\mathbf{q} a^\dagger_\mathbf{q} b_\mathbf{q} e^{i \mathbf{d}_1 \cdot \mathbf{q}}
-t \sum_\mathbf{q} a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}b_\mathbf{q}e^{i \mathbf{d}_2\cdot \mathbf{q}}
 + \mathrm{h.c.}
\\
=-t\sum_\mathbf{q}a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}b_\mathbf{q}
\left(
1 + e^{i\mathbf{d}_1\cdot\mathbf{q}} + e^{i\mathbf{d}_2\cdot\mathbf{q}}
\right) + \mathrm{h.c.}
\\
=-t\sum_\mathbf{q}
\begin{pmatrix}
a^\dagger_\mathbf{q} & b^\dagger_\mathbf{q}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1 + e^{i\mathbf{d}_1\cdot\mathbf{q}} + e^{i\mathbf{d}_2\cdot\mathbf{q}}
\\
1 + e^{-i\mathbf{d}_1\cdot\mathbf{q}} + e^{-i\mathbf{d}_2\cdot\mathbf{q}}
&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_\mathbf{q} \\ b_\mathbf{q}
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$

There you go!

Comment: thank you al lot !